# Count number of occurrence of a value in several columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

Given the following table:

```
PERSON    IS_EMPLOYED        IS_MARRIED        IS_STUDENT

John        Y                   N                Y 
Tom         N                   Y                N
Rob         N                   N                N
Ron         Y                   Y                Y
```

How can I count total Y's and N's for each person so that I get the following result?

```
PERSON     TOTAL_Y         TOTAL_N

 John        2               1
 Tom         1               2
 Rob         0               3
 Ron         3               0
```

I am using Access and I can do it using VBA but I wonder if there's a quicker solution that can be implemented just using SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below query

```
SELECT
   Person,
   IFF(IS_EMPLOYED = 'Y', 1,0) + IFF(IS_MARRIED = 'Y', 1,0)+ IFF(IS_STUDENT = 'Y', 1,0)  AS TOTAL_Y,
   IFF(IS_EMPLOYED = 'N', 1,0) + IFF(IS_MARRIED = 'N', 1,0)+ IFF(IS_STUDENT = 'N', 1,0)  AS TOTAL_N
FROM Persons;
```

Comment: @Sn_Srm Glad to have helped you!

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to do this. A union query would be a good choice since it would be easy to expand on, or add more calculations to in the future:

```
SELECT
    person,
    sum(iif(yesno='Y', 1, 0)) as Total_Y,
    sum(iif(yesno='N', 1, 0)) as Total_N
FROM
    (     
        SELECT person, is_employed as yesno FROM table
        UNION ALL
        SELECT person, is_married FROM table
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT person, is_student FROM table
    ) AS yesnoquery
GROUP BY person
```